# How much time it takes to activate s3 bucket policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy, bucket

I just want to know How much time it takes to activate s3 bucket policy?

Every time i create bucket policy it take approx 5 to 10 minute to activate it.

I Just want to know is there any setting from where i can set timing or it's normal to take 5-10 Minute to activate S3 Bucket policy.

Comment: There is no setting to change. I find it normally takes a few seconds. Please Edit your question and describe what you are doing and how you are testing whether the bucket policy has updated. (It might be that your browser is caching content!)